# How to attach a 'descending panel' to the bottom of the Menubar in QMainWindow

Tags: c++, qt4

When you save a file on a Mac, a panel kinda descends down from the top bar in a really cool way. I want to create a class that does a similar thing using the Qt framework. There are a number of things that I'm confused about:

1. When the panel descends, input to the parent window should be blocked. This is easy with QDialog as it has the setModal() method, however - QDialogs, by default pop-out. I'm not sure how to get around this.
2. In a QMainProject, there is a QMenua new instance of the DescendingPanel class is created. How would you do that, supposing there are other widgets below the menubar. The DescendingPanel should appear above them.

I would really appreciate any help with this.

**EDIT**

I had an idea that instead of pegging the dialog under the menubar, just make it appear under there and remove the window frame. That way, it would give an illusion that it popped out from under there. Ofcourse, Move events would also have to be handled so that the Dialog is always under the menubar but that's for later. Here's the code I used to get the DescendingDialog to appear under the menubar.

```
class DescendingDialog : public QWidget
{
    QMainWindow* Window;
    QWidget*     Menu;
    QPoint       GlobalLocationOfMenu;
    int          DialogWidth;
    int          DialogHeight;

    int X()
    {
        int XDistanceOfPanel = GlobalLocationOfMenu.x() + ((Menu->width()/2) - (this->DialogWidth/2));
        //GlobalLocationOfMenu.x() returns 0;
        return XDistanceOfPanel;
    }

    int Y()
    {
        int YDistanceOfPanel = GlobalLocationOfMenu.y()+Menu->height();
        //GlobalLocationOfMenu.y() returns 0;
        return YDistanceOfPanel;
    }

    void SetGeometry()
    {
        this->setGeometry(this->X(),this->Y(),this->DialogWidth,this->DialogHeight);

    }
public:
    DescendingDialog(QMainWindow*   Window,int DialogWidth,int DialogHeight):QWidget(NULL)
    {
       this->Window = Window;
       this->Menu   = this->Window->menuWidget();
       this->DialogWidth = DialogWidth;
       this->DialogHeight = DialogHeight;

       QPoint RelativeLocationOfMenu = this->Menu->pos();
       this->GlobalLocationOfMenu = QWidget::mapToGlobal(RelativeLocationOfMenu);
       this->SetGeometry();

    }
};
```

It didn't work because the GlobalLocationOfMenu.x() and .y() returned 0 so the dialog doesn't appear where I want it to.

Comment: I just had an idea. Instead of pegging the dialog to the bottom of the QToolbar, I could try to set it's coordinates in a relative way so that the panel always appears below the toolbar even if the QMainMindow is moved around on the screen. I'm going to see if I can implement that. If it works, then all that's left will be to remove the Glass-Frame (the one that contains the maximise, minimise and close buttons) - removing them would disguise the fact that the dialog is in fact separate window.

Comment: I tried doing the above, but I can't get the Dialog to appear right under the Toolbar. I got the location of the toolbar using pos() and set the position of the dialog relative to the toolbar, but it appeared off-center in most cases.

Comment: did you use mapToGlobal methods? remember that pos will return relative to parent position

Comment: Yes, I did. I always got x and y ordinates of 0 (which is the default value).

Comment: ok, so to make it clear... you call on your QToolBar->mapToGlobal(QPoint(0, 0)) ?

Comment: No, I've added the source code. Did I use the mapToGlobal function wrong?

Comment: You should call mapToGlobal in context of widget you're maping from. So in this case you want to know what is global position for point 0,0 relative to your window

Comment: Yup, I realised that now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can let a dialog "slide in" by using a function similar to that:

```
#include <QDialog>
#include <QPropertyAnimation>
#include <QParallelAnimationGroup>

void makeAppear(QDialog * dialog, QRect geometryEnd)
{
    static QParallelAnimationGroup *animationGroup = 0;
    if (animationGroup)
    {
        for(int i = 0, ie = animationGroup->animationCount(); i != ie; ++i)
            delete animationGroup->animationAt(i);
        delete animationGroup;
    }

    // Set up start and end geometry for 'dialog'.
    QPoint parentTopLeft = dialog->parentWidget()->geometry().topLeft();
    geometryEnd.translate(dialog->parentWidget()->mapToGlobal(parentTopLeft));
    QRect geometryBegin = geometryEnd;
    geometryBegin.setHeight(0);

    // Set up start and end geometry for the only child widget of 'dialog'.
    QWidget * dialogChildWidget = dynamic_cast< QWidget * >(dialog->children().first());
    if ( !dialogChildWidget )
        return;
    QRect childGeometryEnd = dialogChildWidget->geometry();
    QRect childGeometryBegin = childGeometryEnd;
    childGeometryBegin.translate(0, geometryEnd.height() * (-1));

    // Set up animation for 'dialog'.
    QPropertyAnimation *dialogAnimation = new QPropertyAnimation(dialog, "geometry");
    dialogAnimation->setDuration(400);
    dialogAnimation->setStartValue(geometryBegin);
    dialogAnimation->setEndValue(geometryEnd);

    // Set up animation for the only child widget of 'dialog'.
    QPropertyAnimation *childAnimation = new QPropertyAnimation(dialogChildWidget, "geometry");
    childAnimation->setDuration(400);
    childAnimation->setStartValue(childGeometryBegin);
    childAnimation->setEndValue(childGeometryEnd);

    // Set up (and start) a parallel animation group
    animationGroup = new QParallelAnimationGroup;
    animationGroup->addAnimation(dialogAnimation);
    animationGroup->addAnimation(childAnimation);
    animationGroup->start();

    // Make 'dialog' visible, borderless, modal.
    dialog->setModal(true);
    dialog->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::Dialog);
    dialog->show();
}
```

The `dialog` argument shall point to a (hidden/not visible) QDialog instance with one single child widget, that contains all other widgets that belong to the dialog.

The `geometryEnd` argument shall specify position and size of `dialog` after it has appeared (relative to it's parent widget).

The result looks [like this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtuGtH8jTwc).

Comment: + 50! Thanks so much! I got the effect I wanted and I can work really build up from this. Really clear. Thanks again :)